# Is possible use drawable-mdpi-fr, drawable-hdpi-fr, drawable-ldpi-fr, for localization with different resolutions

Tags: android, localization, drawable, resolutions

I want to use different images for different localisations. However, I have images for all resolutions and for all languages. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

yes, it is possible by. drawable-de-rDE-ldpi,drawable-de-rDE-mdpi . check it.

Answer (score 22):

> Is possible use drawable-mdpi-fr, drawable-hdpi-fr, drawable-ldpi-fr, for localization with different resolutions

Yes.

Obviously, this gets tedious for too many translations, and if there are too many affected images your APK size may grow substantially. Since Android will automatically rescale images, you might try just `res/drawable-fr-xhdpi/` and see what it looks like on lower-density devices.

Comment: I think the language code comes first, so it should be _res/drawable-fr-xhdpi/_

Comment: @candiru: Absolutely correct -- I have corrected the non-quoted portions of my answer to match. My apologies.

Comment: @CommonsWare ..... i have an question..please help!!! I want the spainsh drwable for my app, so i have created the resource folder like drawable-hdpi-es , drawable-xhdpi-es, drawable-xxhdpi-es,drawable-xxxhdpi-es Is it right or m i doing somethong wrong..please help sir