# How to Localise android drawable resources?

Tags: android, localization, android-resources

I am trying to localise an app I wrote for french, german, spanish, and polish. For all strings I have achieved this by adding folders: values-de, values-fr, values-es and values-pl and translating the strings.xml in each folder into the respective languages. I am having trouble doing this with the images I am using, I have a tab host layout that displays an image for each tab. I have tried adding into resources the following folders: drawable-de-hdpi, drawbale-fr-hdpi, drawable-pl-hdpi, drawabel-es-hdpi(done for each pixed density respectively), and putting the correct images corresponding to the countries in each. However when I change the phone settings to French for example the strings translate fine on the app, but the images remain in the english setting.

Please note the possible previous solution @PedroHawk linked I had already tried and did not work for me thanks!

Comment: x=language, y=density(eg drawable-fr-hdpi) is what I tried

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is possible use drawable-mdpi-fr, drawable-hdpi-fr, drawable-ldpi-fr, for localization with different resolutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349851/is-possible-use-drawable-mdpi-fr-drawable-hdpi-fr-drawable-ldpi-fr-for-locali)

Comment: @PedroHawk I had already seen this question and neither solutions worked!

Answer (score 4):

- Use for placing Spanish drawables - drawable-es-rES-hdpi
- Use for placing German drawables - drawable-de-rDE-hdpi
- Use for placing French drawables - drawable-fr-rFR-hdpi
- Use for placing Polish drawables - drawable-pl-rPL-hdpi

You can create different density-wise folders in similar way.
Goodluck!